# ios7: Pull to refresh does not show up on simulator

Tags: ios, pull-to-refresh

I am pretty new to `iOS` programming and for a class project I was trying to implement "pull to refresh feature"

I tried from this [link](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/ios-6-pull-to-refresh-uirefreshcontrol/), and implemented same in my `MoviesViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.moviesTableView.delegate = self;
    self.moviesTableView.dataSource = self;

    // pull to refresh
    UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to Refresh"];
    [refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refresh;

    // progress bar
    MBProgressHUD *HUD = [self getLoadingController];
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(generateMovies) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

    self.moviesTableView.rowHeight = 100;
    [self.moviesTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MovieViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MovieViewCell"];
}
```

and

```
-(void)refreshView:(UIRefreshControl *)refresh {
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refreshing data..."];

    // custom logic: get data from server
    NSLog(@"refreshing view");


    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
    NSString *lastUpdated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last updated on %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:lastUpdated];
    [refresh endRefreshing];
}
```

But when I run this in simulator, I do not see it while pulling down the movies table.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have a UITableViewController, or a plan UIViewController? It looks like a plain UIViewController, since you're apparently referencing a UITableView and setting its dataSource and delegate. If so, I think that a UIRefreshControl will not work in a scenario like this. I believe it only works for UITableViewController instances.

Comment: i think you forgot to addSubview the UIRefreshControl in UITableView..  Try [self.tblVideoView addSubview:refresh];

Comment: Adding the refresh control is not working in simulator, but it worked on the device for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing adding the HUD into the refresh control.  Depending on your view structure, you'd need something like:

```
[self.refreshLoadingView addSubview:self.hud];
```

We'd need to see the rest of your code to debug the problem, but here's a tutorial I wrote explaining custom pull-to-refresh controls for iOS (including Swift): http://www.jackrabbitmobile.com/design/ios-custom-pull-to-refresh-control/